# How to run "file exist" function (expect/tcl) as condition during a while loop?

Tags: ssh, while-loop, expect, file-exists, not-exists

I know that this is a similar question to other posts but after trying variants of their code I have not been able to get the result I want. The expect script logs in, submits a cluster job and waits for the resulting file to be written. I want to check periodically for the result file and move on in my expect script after the file is in the directory. When I run the following code, the `[file exists outgraph.json]` never appears to equal `1` even after I see the file in another ssh session. I think I am overlooking something simple but cannot figure out why it never detects the file during the loop resulting on the expect script never moving forward.

```
#Attempt 1
#Spawning and logging in
send "qsub -v QUERY=$query run\_query.pbs\r"
while {true} {
    after 2000
    if {[file exists outgraph.json] == 1} {
    break;
    }
    puts [file exists outgraph.json]
}
expect "$ "
send "rm -rf tmp1\r";
expect "$ "
send "rm input.fa\r";
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
# moving file with sftp

#Attempt 2
# spawning and logging in
send "qsub -v QUERY=$query run\_query.pbs\r"
set fexist [file exists outgraph.json]
while {$fexist == 0} {
    after 2000;
    set fexist [file exists outgraph.json]
    puts $fexist
} 
expect "$ "
send "rm -rf tmp1\r";
expect "$ "
send "rm input.fa\r";
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
# moving file with sftp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of `file exists`. It checks the file path present or not, only in the local machine wherever you are running the `Expect` script, **not in the remote directory.**

```
#This is a common approach for few known prompts
#If your device's prompt is missing here, then you can add the same.
set prompt "#|>|\\\$ $"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'

set filename outgraph.json
set cmd "(\[ -f $filename ] && echo PASS) || echo FAIL" 
send "$cmd\r"
expect {
    "\r\nPASS" { puts "File is available";exp_continue}
    "\r\nFAIL" { puts "File is not available";exp_continue}
    -re $prompt 
}
```

Comment: Hey Dinesh, I put a loop around the above code and it does exactly what I need. Thanks again!